# Port is closed,Android chat Application

Tags: android, networking, xmpp, openfire, smack

During the last couple of months I've been creating my own chat application. I used the **XMPP** protocol, and for implementation I used the **Smack library** for creating Android clients and **Openfire** as server.

I always tested the app in a local network and in my network port **5222** (the port that Openfire uses for connection between client and server) is open.

I moved my Openfire server to a host and struggled to connect the app to the server, and I found that port 5222 is closed by my ISP and my mobile network provider as well.
So here are two questions:

1. Is there any solution to somehow bypass this restriction?
2. In Openfire I can change my port, but I don't know if there is a standard port for this kind of application.

   I tested my ISP's IP address by [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and all common ports were closed and port 80 as well. but i can use browser and see any website. i also can use ftp (port 21) so why i can use some close ports ??

Comment: The typical solution is to have an intermediate server that both apps communicate to and that proxies communication between the two. This way, both apps only make outbound requests (which firewalls don't block), and only the server needs to handle inbound requests.

Comment: can you explain more (details) , i don't know any thing about proxies , intermediate server and any network related thing about them

Comment: Added an answer which clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, instead of:

```
 =========               =========
 = app 1 =  <----------> = app 2 =
 =========               =========
```

You would do:

```
 =========               =========
 = app 1 =  ----------> = server =
 =========               =========
                            ^
 =========                  |
 = app 2 =  -----------------
 =========
```

That is, firewalls typically disallow **inbound** connections, but not **outbound** connections. So, to get around this, you set up a server using a hosting service that accepts inbound requests, and then all other apps/nodes (which may be behind a firewall) initiate requests to the server (rather than listening on a local port and waiting to be contacted by the server). The server then acts as an intermediary to forward requests between the two (so that the apps can also receive and not just send data).

For something like receiving frequent messages, you can basically contact the intermediary server at a regular interval, and ask it if there are any new messages (if so, download them, and notify the user; if not disconnect and go back to sleep to check-in again later). However, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel here; [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) already does exactly this. So, basically, your intermediary server should receive / store the XMPP messages on behalf of the Android app, but then it should forward this information to the Android app using GCM (so that the Android app takes advantage of GCM's regular check-ins without adding its own battery-eating check-ins).

Now, in terms of the intermediary server, you can check to see if there are other ports that your ISP allows through (the port that you use, aside from the need to not conflict with other apps on the server, really only matters in terms of discoverability; e.g., is this XMPP application intended to interoperate with other XMPP clients? If so, do those clients allow the user to specify a custom port number, or do they assume a specific port?). However, it's possible that the ISP blocks all ports, in which case, I'm afraid there isn't much you can do except use a hosting service that is specifically expecting inbound traffic and that has unblocked ports. If you are hosting this on your own consumer ISP connection, you may find that this is simply not a viable option with your ISP. I suggest you look into alternative hosting options; personally, I'm biased in favor [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/), but many options abound.

Comment: thanks for your guidance , if i understand well , you are suggesting me to use a server between apps , so this is what i'm used (your 2nd figure). the Openfire witch is a real time collaboration (RTC) serve , i also reinvent the wheel and there not problem. i can use any Not reserved port . i can even open the port of My host .but not my mobile network provider or any other providers. i was wondering if it possible to use any kind of proxy or vpn or using a port which should be considered open for this situation by providers or maybe other way that i'm not aware of. thanks a lot

Comment: Where are you hosting this openfire server? I believe I addressed that with my last paragraph... that is, you probably will not be able to host this server using a consumer ISP connection; you probably will need to pay a hosting service in order to be able to do this.

Comment: yeah exactly as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If there's another port that is not filtered, and you have control over your DNS configuration, you can change Openfire to listen on that port and then use DNS SRV records to make XMPP clients find the right port.

For example, if your XMPP server is `example.net` and listens on port 1234, add the following SRV record:

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 1234 example.net.
```

XMPP clients will look this up before connecting, and discover that they need to use port 1234 instead of 5222.  You can even specify a different server name to connect to:

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 1234 server.example.net.
```

There is some more detail on [the SRV Records page on the XMPP wiki](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records).

Comment: i cant find any port that is open. even common port (80 , 21, ..) are closed. if so, how i'm capable of opening websites and connect to my host using ftp ??

Comment: That's strange. You could ask a new question about that, providing details about what you've tried, how you're checking which ports are open, etc.